# HTML textarea won't POST

Tags: php, html, post

When I check, using PHP, if $_POST['area'] ISSET it returns false. Here is my HTML, does anyone see what is wrong?

```
<form action="phpPostLog.php" method= "POST">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
        <textarea  rows="4" cols="50" id="area" name="area" value="area"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value = "submit">
    </form>
```

$_POST['name'] works fine, but the textarea just won't go through.

Comment: It doesn't need  a value attribute. For textareas, the html you enter is it's value.

Comment: @littleibex It still shouldn't fail `isset($_POST['area'])`. It should be set to the empty string, since that's what's in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar indeed. That's what I thought too. Hence I didn't post it as an answer, but just a suggestion to help out the OP because I thought probably the value attribute was hindering form submission.

Comment: Exactly, removing or keeping value does not affect whether or not it posts. Thanks though.

Comment: Please show `var_dump($_POST)`.

Comment: Bingo. I had the same thing in mind.

Comment: @Barmar array
  'name' => string 'suwyn' (length=5)

Comment: I have never had a problem with this before and it is really frustrating me that I am now :/

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/hdmemxud/

Comment: You need to post more code so we can see what you're doing wrong. It's probably a bug in the server script.

Comment: @Barmar I think you are right. I restarted the server and it works now. That was really weird. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be some problem in your ***phpPostLog.php*** file therefore as you have not given your PHP code i just gave a basic example to show how to properly retrieve user inputs from the form.

***The form page***

```
 <form action="phpPostLog.php" method= "POST">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
            <textarea  rows="4" cols="50" id="area" name="area" ></textarea><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

***phpPostLog.php***

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$area = $_POST['area'];
echo $name;
$echo $area;
 }
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution? What did you change that should fix it?

Comment: as he/she did not gave the PHP code , where i think the problem exists therefore i just gave the code to compare if his php code is similar to this and if there is some error that might be found.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `value="area"` from your

```
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50" id="area" name="area" value="area"></textarea>
```

Comment: An unrecognized attribute shouldn't prevent the field from posting.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea does not have value attribute instead value for textarea is enclosed in opening and closing textarea tag.

Comment: This is the same as other people posted. It was the wrong answer then, it's still the wrong answer. Extra attributes are just ignored, they won't cause the field to fail to post.